# OpenCV Android Green Color Detection

Tags: android, opencv, colors, rgba, hsv

currently I'm making an app where user will detect green colors. I use this photo for testing:
[image]

My problem is that I can not detect any green pixel. Before I worked with blue color and everything worked fine. Now I can't detect anything though I tried different combinations of `RGB`. I wanted to know whether it's problem with green or my detection range, so I made an image in paint using `(0, 255, 0)` and it worked. Why it can't see this circle then? I use this code for detection:

```
Core.inRange(hsv_image, new Scalar([I change this value]), new Scalar(60, 255, 255), ultimate_blue);
```

It could have been that I set wrong Range, but I use Photoshop to get color of one of green pixels and convert `RGB` value of it into `HSV`. Yet it doesn't work. It don't detect even pixel that I've sampled. What's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Using Miki's answer:

[image]

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31465462/5008845)

Comment: I think I use HSV right. I use http://colorizer.org/ to find out corresponding HSV for RGB and then convert it, so it can be used in OpenCV.

Comment: I updated the answer, you need to use a lower bound for V, since your original image is quite dark (i.e. low V). See the result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Green color is HSV space has H = 120 and it's in range [0, 360].

OpenCV halves the H values to fit the range [0,255], so H value instead of being in range [0, 360], is in range [0, 180].
S and V are still in range [0, 255].

As a consequence, the value of H for green is 60 = 120 / 2.

You upper and lower bound should be:

```
// sensitivity is a int, typically set to 15 - 20 
[60 - sensitivity, 100, 100]
[60 + sensitivity, 255, 255]
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since your image is quite dark, you need to use a lower bound for V. With these values:

```
sensitivity = 15;
[60 - sensitivity, 100, 50]  // lower bound
[60 + sensitivity, 255, 255] // upper bound
```

the resulting mask would be like:

[image]

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465462/5008845) for the details.

Comment: I've used your values and made sensitivity to 60. I've uploaded image of what I get. Lighter pixels are those that I detect.

Comment: OMG! Thanks. You don't even realize how useful this answer is. When I struggled to detect blue circles I used up to 10 inRange to filter enough pixels to detect color. And here you do it with one function. I feel so stupid.