# Change one specific color of bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, colorfilter, android-color

I have an `ImageView` loading a bitmap. In this bitmap, I want to replace all pixels of a given color with another color. I've searched extensively for this, but most answers seem to either refer to using a standard `ColorFilter` (which applies the tint to *all* pixels) or manually looping through all pixels and replacing the color if it matches a given input color.

Is there really not a more standardized way of applying a filter only to a given single color? Or creating a mask from a bitmap and a given single color and then apply the filter using that mask? I would be very surprised if I'd had to manually mutate the bitmap and write code to alter every pixel!?
Note that I also want to make sure antialiasing etc is not destroyed. When using standard `ColorFilter`/`android:tint`, antialiasing in rounded corners etc is preserved. I simply want to apply the filter selectively for a given color or range of colors. Is there any API for this?

Answer (score 0):

Open CV for Android seems like something you need:
https://opencv.org/platforms/android/

Here you can find examples of finding pixels of given color: [OpenCV Android Green Color Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590499/opencv-android-green-color-detection/31590723)

If your bitmap is some sort of real photo and you are looking for something that will catch some part of color spectre than OpenCV is probably the best choice.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I don't need to support any photo; it's sufficient if I can replace e.g. all white portions of an icon that contains a few distinct colors (while still preserving anti-aliasing). As an example, imagine an image containing a white shape with some grey text and some green symbols on it - I want to be able to replace white with an arbitrary color while not affecting the grey or green.

Comment: Well if we are talking about very simple picture than I don't know any better solution than something like this: https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/image-processing-pixel-color-replacement/ Which is iterating thourgh pixels and changing their color manually as you descibed it.

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling that will create severe edge artifacts though. I was hoping there was a standard Android API that I had overlooked to produce a mask for a given color, with a given tolerance, but it seems not.

Comment: At least nothing I know. And yes, such simple solution will not deal in any acceptable manner with shades or anything like this. But openCV does. Choice is yours