# how can i track GREEN color in openCV? while red&blue worked

Tags: python, opencv

red and blue works fine, what happened to GREEN.
i've read [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590499/opencv-android-green-color-detection) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv),still doesn't work.
see my picture [frame,mask,res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQdMj.jpg)

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
while(1):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
    lower_green = np.array([45,100,20])
    upper_green = np.array([75,255,255])
    lower_red = np.array([0,100,100])
    upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])
    mask1 = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    mask2 = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
    mask3 = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask1+mask2+mask3)
    cv.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv.imshow('mask',mask1+mask2+mask3)
    cv.imshow('res',res)
    k = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your mask might not be able to represent the Green color which you are trying to track. It seems like your Hue values for lower and upper green are actually redish colors.

Comment: i run `green=np.uint8([[[0,255,0]]])
hsv_green=cv.cvtColor(green,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
print(hsv_green)`,result is `[[[ 60 255 255]]]`, so i set lower and upper hue 45(60-15),75(60+15), could you tell me what's wrong with this?@Meto

Comment: I really don't know why cvtColor() produces an output like that. If we think hue like a circle Red falls between 0 and 60 degrees, Yellow falls between 61 and 120 degrees, Green falls between 121 and 180 degrees. And if we scale it to opencv's value range, lower green should be 85.

Comment: lower green[85,100,20]  upper green[105,255,255] works! why 85? i can't figure it out@Meto

Comment: Take a look at here https://programmingdesignsystems.com/color/color-models-and-color-spaces/index.html . There is a 3D HSV model which can help you better grasp the concept.

Comment: If my comment solved your problem, could you mark this question as solved?

Comment: yeah you did solve it thanks! but seems like i can only mark an answer as accepted not a comment? @Meto maybe you could write it as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HSV color space, Hue represents the traditional colors which we perceive. Another main difference is that when RGB color space represented as a cube, HSV is a cylinder so the range of Hue is actually `0 to 360 degrees.` Hue represents Green values between `~121 to ~180` degrees and when we rescale that to the input range of Opencv functions (0-255) the value of green should be between `85 to 128.` If you are looking for a visual representation [this page](https://programmingdesignsystems.com/color/color-models-and-color-spaces/index.html) has a nice interactive model for both RGB and HSV color spaces.