# How can i draw boundary across a particular colour in opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

Suppose I have an image. I basically want to make boundary across a particular colour that I want. I know the hsv minimum and maximum scalar values of that colour. But I don't know how to proceed further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    while(true)
    {
    Mat img;
    cap.read(img);
    Mat dst;
    Mat imghsv;
    cvtColor(img, imghsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    inRange(imghsv,
           Scalar(0, 30, 0),
           Scalar(20, 150, 255),
           dst
           );
    imshow("name",dst);
    if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms
       {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break;
       }
    }
}
```

The inrange function works well but I am not able to draw a boundary across whatever is white (I mean whichever pixel is in the range specified)

Comment: you should post more information: a reference image, the programming language, your HSV bounds

Comment: i.e. an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Since you updated your question with some code, I updated my answer with some code, too! Check it out, and look if it meets your needs. (Next time, please notify people that you updated the question with a comment on the their answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first segment the color, and then find the contours of the segmented image.

**SEGMENT THE COLOR**

Working in HSV is in general a good idea to segment colors. Once you have the correct lower and upper boundary, you can easily segment the color.
A simple approach is to use [inRange](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange).
You can find how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465462/5008845) for example.

**FIND BOUNDARIES**

Once you have the binary mask (obtained through segmentation), you can find its boundaries using [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#findcontours). You can refer to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) or [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html) to know how to use `findContours` to detect the boundary, and `drawContours` to draw it.

---

**UPDATE**

Here a working example on how to draw a contour on segmented objects.
I used some morphology to clean the mask, and changed to tracked color to be blue, but you can put your favorite color.

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    while (true)
    {
        Mat img;
        cap.read(img);
        Mat dst;
        Mat imghsv;
        cvtColor(img, imghsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        inRange(imghsv, Scalar(110, 100, 100), Scalar(130, 255, 255), dst); // Detect blue objects


        // Remove some noise using morphological operators
        Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(7,7));
        morphologyEx(dst, dst, MORPH_OPEN, kernel);

        // Find contours
        vector<vector<Point>> contours;
        findContours(dst.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        // Draw all contours (green)
        // This 
        drawContours(img, contours, -1, Scalar(0,255,0));

        // If you want to draw a contour for a particular one, say the biggest...

        // Find the biggest object
        if (!contours.empty())
        {
            int idx_biggest = 0;
            int val_biggest = contours[0].size();

            for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
            {
                if (val_biggest < contours[i].size())
                {
                    val_biggest = contours[i].size();
                    idx_biggest = i;
                }
            }

            // Draw a single contour (blue)
            drawContours(img, contours, idx_biggest, Scalar(255,0,0));

            // You want also the rotated rectangle (blue) ?

            RotatedRect r = minAreaRect(contours[idx_biggest]);

            Point2f pts[4];
            r.points(pts);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            {
                line(img, pts[j], pts[(j + 1) % 4], Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
            }
        }

        imshow("name", dst);
        imshow("image", img);

        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms
        {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a particular hue to be detected then you can create a mask to select only the particular color from your original image.

on the hue channel (img):

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.size(),CV_8UC1);

for(int i=0;i<img.rows;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<img.cols;i++){
        if(img.at<uchar>(i,j)==(uchar)specific_hue){
            mask.at<uchar>(i,j)=(uchar)255;
        }
    }
}

color_img.copyTo(masked_image, mask);
```

If you want something less rigorous, you can define a range around the color to allow more image to pass through the mask.

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.size(),CV_8UC1);
int threshold = 5;

for(int i=0;i<img.rows;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<img.cols;i++){
        if((img.at<uchar>(i,j)>(uchar)(specific_hue - threshold)) && (img.at<uchar>(i,j)<(uchar)(specific_hue + threshold))){
            mask.at<uchar>(i,j)=(uchar)255;
        }
    }
}

color_img.copyTo(masked_image, mask);
```

Comment: are you aware that `inRange` does this exactly? Also, I don't see in the answer the part about drawing boundaries.

Comment: No i didn't know the function, as doing it myself was pretty fast. Thanks for the info.

For the contour on the other hand, i find that the mask can be a good start to then apply what you want for the contour (which wasn't specified by the author). I was thinking for example at something like fitEllipse
But I agree that my answer lacks of that information.

Comment: While your loop works ok in general, for segmenting HSV colors you should also add a constraint on S and V value, usually to have both > 100 (or you segment also very dark to black colors). So for your approach to work, you should also include that. You're also iterating two times on rows, second loop should be `j<img.cols; ++j`. A small tip: Use `Mat1b mask(img.size(), uchar(0));` so you can access it simply with `mask(i,j)`. Other tip: don't use C cast, i.e. use `uchar(xxx)` instead of `(uchar)xxx`.