# Get right HSV color inRange in OpenCV (Java)

Tags: java, opencv, colors, hsv

I have following imaged, preprocessed with certain OpenCV functions:

[image: Different colored lego bricks]

Now I'm trying to get the number of bricks of each color (in this case 1 for every color). These are all colors I have.

My plan was to loop through all colors, use the OpenCV function "inRange" and get the area size. My problem is to recognize the different colors. I tried the red color and struggled on finding a good range. After asking google I understood, that I have to use HSV colors, to get a good range with the hue value.

So I wrote this code (in Java for some reason):

```
Mat img; //img is given from previos code
Mat hsv = img.clone();
Imgproc.cvtColor(img, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
```

After this I expected to have an image, with which I can get the different colors. In fact I got this:

[image: Weird HSV image]

In this image the colors are almost destroyed...red and light green look the same and other colors are completely different too.

Now my question:
Do I something wrong? Is it possible to distinguish the Lego brick colors? What can I do to achieve this? I'm using OpenCV 3.1.0 for Java.

Thanks alot,
Dennis

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31465462/5008845)

Comment: @Miki Thanks, but this doesn't work for me. For example: I try to get blue. The answers says "blue is 120 +- 15 sensity".  But in the HSV image, there is no blue (in the RGB picture there are 2 blue bricks). My problem ist, that HSV conversion destroys all colors and I can't get the right colors...blue for example is found in the violet board and the right (black) area.

Answer (score 3):

I found my mistake and I'm not proud of it. It was a simple typo. With fixing this and the help of @Miki I'm able to find my colors.

My mistake:

```
Mat img; //img is given from previos code
Mat hsv = img.clone();
Imgproc.cvtColor(img, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);    
Core.inRange(img, lowerBlue, upperBlue, hsv); //img
```

instead of

```
Mat img; //img is given from previos code
Mat hsv = img.clone();
Imgproc.cvtColor(img, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);    
Core.inRange(hsv, lowerBlue, upperBlue, hsv); //hsv
```

In fact...I translated the image to HSV and took the RGB picture for inRange().

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give the Scaler values for lowerBlue and upperBlue ?