# Finding HSV color, OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

I've got this code that can detect a green object when it appears on the screen.

Here is the piece I am trying to alter

```
greenLower = (29, 86, 6)
greenUpper = (64, 255, 255)
```

Now I am trying to have the code to detect the white ball in the following images.

But I have been struggling with it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This needs more detail to be answerable.

Comment: white in HSV means to have saturation (2nd channel) close to zero, afaik. so try something like whiteLower = (0,0,minV); whiteUpper = (255,lowValue,255); For minV you have to choose something not too low to not get all the dark gray and black stuff, too.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31465462/5008845)

Comment: that made the trick. thanks