# What would be the hsv range for this in Opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, hsv

I am a bit confused right now, i can't find the correct value for this green square. Here is the image
[image]

The hsv values that i choose are:-

```
cv::inRange(src, Scalar(25, 20, 20), Scalar(85, 255, 200), src);
```

Here is the output from this:-
[image]

What is the correct value for hsv that i should choose?

Answer (score 1):

These ranges should work good enough:

```
inRange(hsv, Scalar(35, 20, 20), Scalar(85, 255, 255), mask);
```

[image]

Remember that OpenCV stores images as BGR, and not RGB. So when you convert to HSV be sure to use `COLOR_BGR2HSV`, and not `COLOR_RGB2HSV`.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat3b hsv;
    cvtColor(img, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Mat1b mask;
    inRange(hsv, Scalar(35, 20, 20), Scalar(85, 255, 255), mask);

    imshow("Mask", mask);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

You can find additional details on HSV ranges [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465462/5008845) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32523532/5008845)

Comment: Thanks, it was a silly mistake i forgot to convert it to HSV..... Also can you tell me how to pick inrange values for HSV i don't know how to find them....