# RGB, HSV concept

Tags: image-processing, rgb, hsv

I found an image [stating the difference between RGB and HSV color spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Klnp.jpg). But from the image, it looks like that they are just different ways of representing the same color, yet when we display them on our screen(e.g. using OpenCV) they look different. I mean though HSV space separates luminance from the color, the actual color should remain same.

Also for displaying an HSV image on the laptop screen, we will need the RGB values, what are those RGB values?

Comment: "when we display them on our screen they look different" No, they don't. If they do, you're not displaying the image right. If you take HSV, and send it to a screen that will interpret it as RGB (i.e. the H channel as the R channel, the S channel as the G channel, etc.) then yes, the colors will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**You said it yourself:**

> "they are just different ways of representing the same color"

Since they are simply *different representations*, you can convert between the formats. There are already SO posts on that: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018313/algorithm-to-convert-rgb-to-hsv-and-hsv-to-rgb-in-range-0-255-for-both), and this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460267/python-opencv-color-tracking#31465462).

RGB and HSV are useful in different applications. HSV seperates the color information from brightness information, which can be useful when comparing colors in image processing, for example. RBG is typically how screens display images.

As Cris said, you should **not** see these displayed differently.