# What is the best approach for isolating a single area of similar colour?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have a satellite image and am trying to isolate one roof based on it's color. My plan is to take the color of a chosen point in the image, and create a slightly lighter > slightly darker range from it (allowing for variation based on sun and shade) and to remove all colors other than those within the range.

Then I need to keep only the color area that contains the originally selected point.

Below is an example sample image, color range and final image I would like to achieve edited manually in photoshop.

I have also had trouble converting an RGB color to HSV values that produce predictable results in the following script. I have tried following various guides for green-screening using python, e.g:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315895/simple-method-to-extract-specific-color-range-from-an-image-in-python) and [this](https://realpython.com/python-opencv-color-spaces/).

I have been trying to use the following but am running into a few issues:

```
img = cv2.imread("static.jpg".format(latlon, zoom))
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# light color in RGB = [153, 139, 130]
# dark color in RGB = [82, 74, 71]
# How to convert these to HSV?
# using 150,0,0 here as it creates a valid range
hsv_color1 = np.array([150,0,0])

# using 180,255,255 here as it creates a valid range
hsv_color2 = np.array([180,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, hsv_color1, hsv_color2)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imwrite("mask.jpg".format(latlon, zoom), mask)
cv2.imshow('img_hsv', img_hsv)
cv2.imwrite("img_hsv.jpg".format(latlon, zoom), img_hsv)
cv2.imshow('res', res)
cv2.imwrite("res.png".format(latlon, zoom), res)
```

So my 2 questions are:

1. How to convert RGB to HSV values that will create a valid inRange to isolate these colours?
2. How to only one area of inRange colour based on a given pixel position?
3. And for a bonus point, how to make the mask for the isolated inRange area a nice tight mask?

I need to output an image that isolates the color area around a given pixel position.

Original
[image: ORIGINAL]

Desired Output
[image: DESIRED OUTPUT]

Light colour
[image: LIGHT COLOR]

Dark colour
[image: DARK COLOR]

Comment: Err, you didn't give us the *"given pixel position"*.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - for example x:235,y:343.

I am also trying to detect the contours for each part on the roof. I have the following to get HSV values from an RGB colour:
```python
    start_r = 154
    start_g = 141
    start_b = 132

    end_r = 82
    end_g = 74
    end_b = 71

    start = np.uint8([[[start_b,start_g,start_r ]]])
    hsv_start = cv2.cvtColor(start,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[0][0]
    end = np.uint8([[[end_b,end_g,end_r ]]])
    hsv_end = cv2.cvtColor(end,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[0][0]

    print (hsv_start)
    print (hsv_end)
```

But I still get an empty mask ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dark value becomes 16/13/32 in HSV. And your light value becomes 23/14/60 in HSV.

OpenCV scales the Hue values by dividing by 2 so that the full range of 360 becomes 180 and still fits into an unsigned 8-bit number. So, you need to use a dark Hue value of 8 and a light Hue value of 12. I would widen that range by 3-5 at each end to allow some leeway, and use a lowish saturation to only pick up unsaturated, greyish values. So the code becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("static.jpg")
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# light color in RGB = [153, 139, 130]
# dark color in RGB = [82, 74, 71]

hsv_lo = np.array([5,0,0])
hsv_hi = np.array([15,50,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, hsv_lo, hsv_hi)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)
cv2.imwrite("result.png", res)
```

[image]