# Count number of pixels with certain color value range

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I need to count the number of pixels in an image (loaded via OpenCV in Python), which have a certain color.

However, I don't need to count *one* specific color (= RGB combo), but also pixels with a color close to that color I am looking for.

See for example this image:

[image]

Here I need to count the number of pixels that have this light green-blue color. But as you can see there is not only one single RGB combo with this color, there is a range of colors in this green-blue-ish tone.

What would be a fast way to count not only those pixels with a certain color value but also pixels that are "close" to this value?

Comment: have you checked <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315895/simple-method-to-extract-specific-color-range-from-an-image-in-python">this</a>, I think you are looking for `cv2.inrange()` where you specify an range for which you want to create mask

Comment: @Epsi95 That looks great, thanks!