# How to detect some pixels with desired color?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a problem: There is a map where crystals randomly appear and I somehow need to find crystal coordinates(need only one crystal's pixel coordinate), I tried to do it by the color of a specific pixel, but after some time, the pixel shade appears and it does not find it (with axis = 2). Can anyone help I would be very grateful.Maybe some size parameter should be used as it doesn't change. (python)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('photos\\temp_3.png')

# Define the blue colour we want to find - remember OpenCV uses BGR ordering
crystal = [0,248,0]

# Get X and Y coordinates of all blue pixels
Y, X = np.where(np.all(im==crystal,axis=2))

print(X, Y)
```

photo examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to try a range of colors, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315895/simple-method-to-extract-specific-color-range-from-an-image-in-python). Also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv/59906154#59906154) to choose your color range

Comment: [Template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) could be another possible approach.