# Is there a way to get the HSV values from the object?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, hsv

Is there a way I can get HSV range/values for the colour I want to separate?

I want to detect `4` by creating the mask for which I would require the `HSV` values.

[image]

The number `4` is in blue color and I tried the following:

```
lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50]) 
upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
image_blue = cv2.inRange(img, lower_blue, upper_blue)
```

On applying the above mask, all I get is a black image. Is there some way I can know the `HSV` values?

Comment: You need to convert your image to HSV before you apply a threshold using HSV values. Once your image is in HSV, you can also see what the values are of the pixels composing the 4.

Comment: cv2: [Changing Colorspaces](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966#47483966

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python opencv color tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460267/python-opencv-color-tracking)